# "React is not defined" while using etch in atom?

Tags: atom-editor, etch

I'm trying to make an atom plugin from scratch. I am using [etch](https://github.com/atom/etch) for the use of virtual DOM in atom which gives me coding environment like react. Whenever I'm trying to run the package, it says `React is not defined`, although React is not used in `etch` and it is not present in the `package.json` file of the `etch`. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default JSX uses React.

You need to add `/** @jsx etch.dom */` to the top of your file.

This tells JSX that `<div>` needs to become `etch.dom('div', {})`